# How do I use ${workspaceRoot} for my Electron app in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: electron, visual-studio-code

I have an Electron app that I was able to debug in Visual Studio Code.  After I upgraded to version 0.10.8 it will no longer run.
I am getting the error message below in my launch.json file:

> Relative paths will no longer be automatically converted to absolute ones.  Consider using ${workspaceRoot} as a prefix.
>
> Absolute path to the runtime executable to be used.  Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.

Here is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "My First Electron App",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "$(workspaceRoot}/app/main.js", //ERROR
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "$(workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "$(workspaceRoot}/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron", //ERROR
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the green squiggly line mentioned for the two lines with //ERROR at the end.

I saw this article, but honestly was familiar with VS Code enough to understand how this should be implemented:  https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution

**UPDATE**
I replaced the value for `"cwd"` with `"${workspaceRoot}"` as recommended by Isidor.  The green squiggly line went away.

I updated the error message that I am still seeing on the other two lines.

When I hit `F5` I get this error message:

> request 'launch': runtime executable '/private/var/git/electron-vs-code/$(workspaceRoot}/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron' does not exist

Comment: There is a typo in your json: change the parenthesis after the $ in '$(workspaceRoot}' to a curly brace. This should at least fix the warning.

Comment: Wow, after doing what Isidor recommended, it still wouldn't ran.  Went back and re-read your suggestion and big surprise...it worked.  Feelin' like a newbie.  If you turn your comment into an Answer, I'll accept it.  It was the real solution to my problem, although Isidor also helped.

Comment: Would you consider sharing the details of how you were able to debug the Electron from VSCode? Did you reference an article?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in your json. Change the parenthesis after the `$` in `$(workspaceRoot}` to a curly brace. This should at least fix the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you are getting the relative path warning VSCode still automatically converts relative to absolute paths in 0.10.8. To get rid of the warnings for "cwd", instead of "." please put "${workspaceRoot}".

What happens when you run try to debug your electron app, do you see some other error, since the relative to absolute can not be the true cause of this. If you command palette / open developper tools -> do you see some error in the console?

Comment: Thanks Isidor, after making your changes, I posted the "Update" above.  After fixing my typos (as recommended by Andre).  It worked!