# Can't get Visual Studio Code to run my build command in launch.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, babeljs, visual-studio-code

I have this command that I can run in a command prompt just fine and it works:

`browserify -u jquery /public/index.js -t babelify -o /public/scripts/bundle.js & node /server.js`

I'm trying to add it to the `launch.json` `program` section in VS Code but I keep getting errors like `relative paths will no longer be converted to absolute ones`.

So I tried changing it to this:

`"program": "browserify -u jquery ${workspaceRoot}/public/index.js -t babelify -o ${workspaceRoot}/public/scripts/bundle.js & node ${workspaceRoot}/server.js"`

And I'm still getting the same error. I think it might need paths for browserify and other executables too but I'm not sure. I tried adding `${workspaceRoot}` to them as well but no luck: same error.

Comment: [This any use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305358/how-do-i-use-workspaceroot-for-my-electron-app-in-visual-studio-code), particularly re `cwd`?

Comment: @Andy: He just had a typo in his workspaceRoot thing.

Comment: Yes but he also had something other than `"cwd": "${workspace}" and the second answerer pointed it out. I thought it might be relevant.

Comment: @Andy: Oh, yeah, my cwd line is already that. The cwd line doesn't have any errors; only the "program" line.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm very new to VS Code and not sure if this is right or not, but I found out I can just put the compilation part in a task (`tasks.json`) and run it with `Control+Shift+B`.

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "browserify",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "suppressTaskName": true,
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "install",
      "isBuildCommand": true,
      "args": ["--u", "jquery", "${workspaceRoot}/public/index.js", "-t", "babelify", "-o", "${workspaceRoot}/public/scripts/bundle.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And then manually run the server with this in the `launch.json`:

`"program": "${workspaceRoot}/server.js",`

Seems to work, but it would be nice to have it all in one step.

**Edit:** Oh ok you can then add `"preLaunchTask": "install",` to `launch.json` to make it one step. Ok, solved!

Answer (score 0):

Ryan solution will probably work, just came here to point out what was wrong: The template constructs (like ${workspaceRoot} and ${cwd}) won't work in the "program" attribute, that's why we have "args".